# Why can't I connect an external clock oscillator to an ATMEGA64A-AU?

Tags: avr, oscillator, atmega

I've decided to change my crystal oscillator for one of those smaller (and also expensive-er!) [SMD clock oscillators](https://www.wdi.ag/specs/mercury/oszillatoren/xo/SWO.pdf) on ATMEGA64A-AU.

I've found this image on the web, which seems right:

[image]

So I built my schematic like this :

[image]

But I've got all sort of abnormalities in my MCU when I set it to use the external clock.  When I set it back to internal oscillation, the micro controller works like a charm!

I searched for an open source project which used this kind of clock and I found [Pro Micro - 5V/16MHz](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640):

[image]

The schematic of this board makes me more confused.  The open hardware schematic is using a crystal oscillator but the board is using a clock oscillator, I guess they forgot to update the [schematic](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Pro_Micro_v13b.pdf). Why they use two 22PF capacitors above the clock oscillator? Two 22PF capacitor usually use for crystal oscillators.

How can I make this clock work?

**PS**: I don't have an oscilloscope.

**UPDATE1:** I realized that the red board is using a crystal not clock, but my chip is a clock oscillator.

Comment: Did you change the fuse bits?

Comment: @G36 Yes , I've change the fuse bits to use external clock

Comment: Your MCU doesn't have power or bypass caps, and your wiring scheme is really inappropriate for a 16 MHz signal which is into the realm where breadboards become problematic.  At the very least keep the wires short and direct.  Additionally "all sort of abnormality" is not an engineering problem report, you must be *specific*.

Comment: And which pin on mega64 did you use to connect your oscillator?

Comment: *two 22PF capacitor usually use for crystal oscillators.* **No**, you should learn the difference between **a crystal** (which needs those two small capacitors to form a crystal oscillator together with the circuit inside the MCU, that shiny block marked "16.000" on the red PCB, is a **crystal**) and **a crystal oscillator** which is the thing on the breadboard marked "clock oscillator" which does **not** need capacitors but it does need a **supply voltage**.

Comment: @G36 according to datasheet, XTAL1 for external clock.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 1- the breadboard was an example of wiring the external clock, I've implement it on PCB 2- all sort of problem mean, the kind of problem usually caused by oscillator like it gets out of sync with programmer but I don't have an oscilloscope to see it through.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show the **actual implementation** which fails.  Getting out of sync with the programmer is typically a reset issue.

Comment: Voting to close as details of the actual attempt are not provided